# Capture song titles while recording with VLC Player

Tags: vlc-media-player, recording, internet-radio

I use VLC Player to record an internet radio stream and it works well. I would also like to capture the song titles which are displayed in VLC Player while recording. Are there any options to do that?

Comment: What is the format of the file that is saved?

Comment: mp3 at 128 kbit/s